# Как избежать дублирование кода в XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Изучаю WPF, использую библиотеку `HelixToolkit3D`. Во `View` находится четыре `HelixViewport3D`, содержимое которых почти идентично, за исключением позиций камеры и текстур. Как избежать дублирование кода в каждом из `HelixViewport3D`?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="EarthWithClouds4k" ImageSource="/Textures/earth_with_clouds_4k.jpg" />
    <ImageBrush x:Key="EarthWithClouds10k" ImageSource="/Textures/earth_with_clouds_10k.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="EarthAtNight" ImageSource="/Textures/earth_at_night.png" />
    <ImageBrush x:Key="EarthAtNight8k" ImageSource="/Textures/earth_at_night_8k_black.jpg" />
    <ImageBrush x:Key="Moon" ImageSource="/Textures/moon_small.jpg" />
    <ImageBrush x:Key="Stars" ImageSource="/Textures/stars.jpg" />
    <ImageBrush x:Key="Sun" ImageSource="/Textures/sun_small.jpg" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="463*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <t:HelixViewport3D Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="Black" ShowCoordinateSystem="True" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="False" ClipToBounds="False">
        <t:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="0 2 0.5" LookDirection="0 -2 0.45" ></PerspectiveCamera>
        </t:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
        <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/tdrs_no_ants.3ds">
            <t:FileModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <Transform3DGroup>
                    <RotateTransform3D >
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].RotationAngle.X}" Axis="1 0 0"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D >
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].RotationAngle.Y}" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D >
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].RotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="{Binding [Satellite].Scale.X}" ScaleY="{Binding [Satellite].Scale.Y}" ScaleZ="{Binding [Satellite].Scale.Z}"/>
                    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetY="{Binding [Satellite].Translate.Y}"/>
                    <RotateTransform3D >
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].DistanceRotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                </Transform3DGroup>
            </t:FileModelVisual3D.Transform>
        </t:FileModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/fairing_back.obj"/>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/fairing_front.obj"/>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/finishing_stage.obj"/>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/head_back.obj"/>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/head_front.obj"/>
            <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <Transform3DGroup>
                    <RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Rocket].RotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="{Binding [Rocket].Scale.X}" ScaleY="{Binding [Rocket].Scale.Y}" ScaleZ="{Binding [Rocket].Scale.Z}"/>
                    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetY="{Binding [Rocket].Translate.Y}"/>
                    <RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Rocket].DistanceRotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                </Transform3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <t:SphereVisual3D Radius="{Binding [Stars].Radius}">
            <t:SphereVisual3D.BackMaterial>
                <EmissiveMaterial Color="White" Brush="{StaticResource Stars}"/>
            </t:SphereVisual3D.BackMaterial>
        </t:SphereVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <t:SphereVisual3D Center="{Binding [Sun].Center}" Radius="{Binding [Sun].Radius}">
                <t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                    <EmissiveMaterial Color="White" Brush="{StaticResource Sun}"/>
                </t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
            </t:SphereVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <Model3DGroup>
                    <DirectionalLight  Color="White" Direction="1 0 0" />
                </Model3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <t:SphereVisual3D  Radius="{Binding [Earth].Radius}">
            <t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                <MaterialGroup>
                    <DiffuseMaterial Color="White" Brush="{StaticResource EarthWithClouds10k}"/>
                    <EmissiveMaterial Brush="{StaticResource EarthAtNight8k}"/>
                </MaterialGroup>
            </t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
        </t:SphereVisual3D>
        <t:SphereVisual3D Center="{Binding [Moon].Center}" Radius="{Binding [Moon].Radius}">
            <t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial Brush="{StaticResource Moon}"/>
            </t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
        </t:SphereVisual3D>
    </t:HelixViewport3D>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Border.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Border
                Background="Black"
                CornerRadius="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"
                Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"
                />
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Border.OpacityMask>
        <t:HelixViewport3D Background="Black" ShowViewCube="False" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="False" ClipToBounds="False" IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <t:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="0 0 0.001">
                    <PerspectiveCamera.Transform>
                        <Transform3DGroup>
                            <RotateTransform3D >
                                <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="90" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                                </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            </RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D >
                                <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="90" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                                </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            </RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D >
                                <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=value, Mode=TwoWay}" Axis="1 0 0"/>
                                </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            </RotateTransform3D>
                            <TranslateTransform3D OffsetY="{Binding [Rocket].Translate.Y}"/>
                        <RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Rocket].DistanceRotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                    </Transform3DGroup>
                </PerspectiveCamera.Transform>
            </PerspectiveCamera>
        </t:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
        <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/tdrs_no_ants.3ds">
            <t:FileModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <Transform3DGroup>
                    <RotateTransform3D >
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].RotationAngle.X}" Axis="1 0 0"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D >
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].RotationAngle.Y}" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D >
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].RotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="{Binding [Satellite].Scale.X}" ScaleY="{Binding [Satellite].Scale.Y}" ScaleZ="{Binding [Satellite].Scale.Z}"/>
                    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetY="{Binding [Satellite].Translate.Y}"/>
                    <RotateTransform3D >
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].DistanceRotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                </Transform3DGroup>
            </t:FileModelVisual3D.Transform>
        </t:FileModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/fairing_back.obj"/>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/fairing_front.obj"/>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/finishing_stage.obj"/>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/head_back.obj"/>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/head_front.obj"/>
            <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <Transform3DGroup>
                    <RotateTransform3D >
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Rocket].RotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="{Binding [Rocket].Scale.X}" ScaleY="{Binding [Rocket].Scale.Y}" ScaleZ="{Binding [Rocket].Scale.Z}"/>
                    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetY="{Binding [Rocket].Translate.Y}"/>
                    <RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Rocket].DistanceRotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                </Transform3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <t:SphereVisual3D Radius="{Binding [Stars].Radius}">
            <t:SphereVisual3D.BackMaterial>
                <EmissiveMaterial Color="White" Brush="{StaticResource Stars}"/>
            </t:SphereVisual3D.BackMaterial>
        </t:SphereVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <t:SphereVisual3D Center="{Binding [Sun].Center}" Radius="{Binding [Sun].Radius}">
                <t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                    <EmissiveMaterial Color="White" Brush="{StaticResource Sun}"/>
                </t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
            </t:SphereVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <DirectionalLight   Color="White" Direction="1 0 0" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <t:SphereVisual3D  Radius="{Binding [Earth].Radius}">
            <t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                <MaterialGroup>
                    <DiffuseMaterial Color="White" Brush="{StaticResource EarthWithClouds4k}"/>
                    <EmissiveMaterial Brush="{StaticResource EarthAtNight}"/>
                </MaterialGroup>
            </t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
        </t:SphereVisual3D>
        <t:SphereVisual3D Center="{Binding [Moon].Center}" Radius="{Binding [Moon].Radius}">
            <t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial Brush="{StaticResource Moon}"/>
            </t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
        </t:SphereVisual3D>
    </t:HelixViewport3D>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Border.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Border
                Background="Black"
                CornerRadius="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"
                Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"
                />
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Border.OpacityMask>
        <t:HelixViewport3D Background="Black" ShowViewCube="False" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="False" ClipToBounds="False" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <t:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera Position="0 0 0.001" >
                    <PerspectiveCamera.Transform>
                        <Transform3DGroup>
                            <RotateTransform3D >
                                <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="90" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                                </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            </RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D >
                                <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="90" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                                </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            </RotateTransform3D>
                            <TranslateTransform3D OffsetY="{Binding [Rocket].Translate.Y}"/>
                            <RotateTransform3D>
                                <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Rocket].DistanceRotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                                </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            </RotateTransform3D>
                        </Transform3DGroup>
                    </PerspectiveCamera.Transform>
                </PerspectiveCamera>
            </t:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
            <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/tdrs_no_ants.3ds">
                <t:FileModelVisual3D.Transform>
                    <Transform3DGroup>
                        <RotateTransform3D >
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].RotationAngle.X}" Axis="1 0 0"/>
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D >
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].RotationAngle.Y}" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D >
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].RotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                        <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="{Binding [Satellite].Scale.X}" ScaleY="{Binding [Satellite].Scale.Y}" ScaleZ="{Binding [Satellite].Scale.Z}"/>
                        <TranslateTransform3D OffsetY="{Binding [Satellite].Translate.Y}"/>
                        <RotateTransform3D >
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Satellite].DistanceRotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                    </Transform3DGroup>
                </t:FileModelVisual3D.Transform>
            </t:FileModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/fairing_back.obj"/>
                <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/fairing_front.obj"/>
                <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/finishing_stage.obj"/>
                <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/head_back.obj"/>
                <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/head_front.obj"/>
                <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                    <Transform3DGroup>
                        <RotateTransform3D >
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Rocket].RotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                        <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="{Binding [Rocket].Scale.X}" ScaleY="{Binding [Rocket].Scale.Y}" ScaleZ="{Binding [Rocket].Scale.Z}"/>
                        <TranslateTransform3D OffsetY="{Binding [Rocket].Translate.Y}"/>
                        <RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding [Rocket].DistanceRotationAngle.Z}" Axis="0 0 1"/>
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                    </Transform3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <t:SphereVisual3D Radius="{Binding [Stars].Radius}">
                <t:SphereVisual3D.BackMaterial>
                    <EmissiveMaterial Color="Red" Brush="{StaticResource Stars}"/>
                </t:SphereVisual3D.BackMaterial>
            </t:SphereVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <t:SphereVisual3D Center="{Binding [Sun].Center}" Radius="{Binding [Sun].Radius}">
                    <t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                        <EmissiveMaterial Color="Red" Brush="{StaticResource Sun}">
                        </EmissiveMaterial>
                    </t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                </t:SphereVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="1 0 0" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <t:SphereVisual3D  Radius="{Binding [Earth].Radius}">
                    <t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial Color="Red" Brush="{StaticResource EarthWithClouds4k}"/>
                    </t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                </t:SphereVisual3D>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <t:SphereVisual3D Center="{Binding [Moon].Center}" Radius="{Binding [Moon].Radius}">
                <t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
                    <DiffuseMaterial Color="Red" Brush="{StaticResource Moon}"/>
                </t:SphereVisual3D.Material>
            </t:SphereVisual3D>
        </t:HelixViewport3D>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте `UserControl`, который будет включать нужный `HelixViewport3D`, положите в него DependencyProperty типа, описывающего позицию камеры, и привяжитесь к нему. Ваш основной код будет выглядеть так:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="463*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <local:MyViewportControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                             CameraPosition="0 2 0.5"/>
    ...
```

`UserControl`'ы как раз и служат контейнерами повторяющихся параметризируемых кусков UI-кода.